# Is there any library can perform polygons buffering/ inflating/ merge/ overlap at server side?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server, polygon, leaflet, openlayers-2

I have a set of polygon data express in lat long. I would like to perform some tasks (polygon buffering, inflating etc etc ..) in server side and output the result to client side (client is a web page... maybe use leaflet to display the data).

I am new to GIS.

Comment: You could also use something like turf to do these operations on the client side.

Comment: What language are you using server-side?

Comment: The app may need to calculate many polygons at the same time, seems it is better to run in Server side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) in client side (as  Devdatta said) but also on the server. It requires nodejs and spatial data in [geojson](http://geojson.org/) format, the perfect format if you like to render it on a leaflet map.

You can install just the modules that you need:

Buffer: [turf-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-buffer)

Merge: [turf-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-merge)

Overlap: [turf-overlaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-overlaps)

[Here](https://github.com/turfjs/turf-node-example) is an example with node

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this!! Let me try and  implement this out!!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is yes. You might like to clarify what kind of server-side software you have.

You can use GeoServer to do WPS requests.

You could use a Python library like [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html).

Or a [C# library](https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/), or a [Java](http://www.geotools.org/) library, or a [JavaScript](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/intro-to-turf/) library.

Or the QGIS API, or the ArcGIS API or the database, be that [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933965.aspx), [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) or Oracle.

So, to answer your question again. **Yes, you can do spatial operations server-side.**

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am working on Linux environment, mostly use PHP, Python, Shell. As I am not familiar with GIS DataBase, may I ask is it a must to use DB ?